# can not force the pattern to check if the text end with link or any hashtag or @ words

Tags: java, regex

Hello everyone I have the following pattern:

```
 @ or # + 1 or 2 words + : + 1 words or more + link + nothing or any words that has # or @ at the beginning
```

Here is two valid example of that :

```
@justin Trudue:I do not go there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask @cbc #liberal @john
```

and

```
@justin Trudue:I do not go there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
```

but an invalid example would be :

```
@justin Trudue:I do not go there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask cbc
```

or

```
@justin Trudue:I do not go there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask @cbc liberal
```

Here is my code which is not working:

```
[@|#]((?:\\w+\\s?){1,}):\\s?((?:\\w+\\s?){1,})((?:http|https):\\/\\/.+)([@|#]\\w){0,}
```

and here is my java code:

```
private static void patt1(String commentstr){
     String urlPattern = "[@|#]((?:\\w+\\s?){1,}):\\s?((?:\\w+\\s?){1,})((?:http|https):\\/\\/.+)([@|#]\\w){0,}";
     Pattern p = Pattern.compile(urlPattern,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(commentstr);
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("yes");
        }
}
```

what is wrong with my regular expression that is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers are right about `[@|#]` or anchors, however I think your regex doesn't work because in last part:

```
((?:http|https):\\/\\/.+)([@|#]\\w){0,}
```

you use `.+` which capture everything after http part. Then `([@|#]\\w){0,}` will not match as you want, because `\w` can match only one character, so it will match only `@a`, `#c` ect. So the minimum you need to chage to make your regex work is:

```
[@|#]((?:\w+\s?){1,}):\s?((?:\w+\s?){1,})((?:http|https):\/\/\S+)(\s[@|#]\w+){0,}$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zP2dP6/6)

- there is `\S` instead of `.`, so it will not match whitespaces, and
  in effect it will match all characters of url, but stop on first
  space.
- add `\s` and `\w+` (insted of just `\w`) in `(\s[@|#]\w+){0,}$` to
  match content after link.
- And you need `$` in the end, to match only whole lines which desired
  content.

Comment: You can shorten `(?:http|https)` as `https?`. The `[@|#]` is wrong, see my answer for explanation why. `{0,}` is the same as `*`. `{1,}` is the same as `+`.

Comment: @stribizhev You are right, but to show OP why regex didn't work, I changed only what was in my opinion necessary to make it work, so I even left this wrong alternative: `[@|#]`

Answer (score 2):

In your regex, `[@|#]` matches 3 characters: `@`, `|` and `#` as it is not a group, it is a character class. Next issue, you are not using anchors (`^` and `$`) so all possible substrings are searched for.

The regex you are looking for is

```
(?i)^[@#](\S+(?:[ ]+\S+)?):[ ]*(\S+(?:[ ]+\S+)*)[ ]+(https?:\/\/\S*)((?:[ ]+(?=[#@])\S+)*)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zP2dP6/5)

In real-life, `[ ]` can be replaced with `\s`.

[IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/v4vSzG):

```
String pattern = "(?i)^[@#](\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+)?):\\s*(\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+)*)\\s+(https?://\\S*)((?:\\s+(?=[#@])\\S+)*)$";
System.out.println("@justin Trudue:I do not go there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask @cbc #liberal @john".matches(pattern)); 
System.out.println("@justin Trudue:I do not go there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask".matches(pattern)); 
System.out.println("@justin Trudue:I do not go there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask cbc".matches(pattern));
```

Output:

```
true
true
false
```

Comment: Thanks but it is not working with for instance this case:#hello sss: xxx https://t.co/3WHshzDG7m #www  #rrr

Comment: It does now, just `\s*` was necessary after `\S+)?):`. You can actually use even more "lax" version allowing whitespaces between each element: `"(?i)^\\s*[@#]\\s*(\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+)?)\\s*:\\s*(\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+)*)\\s+(https?://\\S*)((?:\\s+(?=[#@])\\S+)*)\\s*$"`. Here is [another IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/RxFnfX).

Answer (score 2):

```
^[@|#]((?:\w+\s?){1,2}):\s?((?:\w+\s?){1,})((?:http|https):\/\/[^\s@#]+)(\s?[@#]\w+)*$
```

See tests here: https://regex101.com/r/iL0nS8/1

Comment: Thank u the only problem is I want it to work with this case as well : #hello #sss: xxx https://t.co/3WHshzDG7m #www #rrr but it just works with #hello sss: xxx https://t.co/3WHshzDG7m #www #rrr